# Issue using insertAfter in a list creating multiple results

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use insertAfter to add HTML for each element inside a list with multiple list items.

If you look at my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/Lf98qczn/6/) you will see I get multiple results in each list item and I can't understand why because in my code I am targeting "each" of the list items, so in my example, I should get one "Read more" in each list item, any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="container">

<ul>
    <li class="eaList">
        <p class="title">
            Title
        </p>
        <p class="date">
            20/20/20
        </p>

    </li>
    <li class="eaList">
        <p class="title">
            Title
        </p>
        <p class="date">
            20/20/20
        </p>

    </li>
    <li class="eaList">
        <p class="title">
            Title
        </p>
        <p class="date">
            20/20/20
        </p>

    </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(".eaList").each(function() {
    $('<p>Read More</p>').insertAfter('.date');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.date` matches all the `class="date"` elements, not just the one in the current `.each()` iteration. You can use `$(this).find('.date')` to match just that one.

```
$(".eaList").each(function() {
    $('<p>Read More</p>').insertAfter($(this).find('.date'));
});
```

But there's no need for the loop, you can do:

```
$(".eaList .date").after('<p>Read More</p>');
```

DOM modification functions automatically iterate over all the selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

i beleave this is what you want

`$('<p>Read More</p>').insertAfter('.eaList>p.date');`

```js
    $('<p>Read More</p>').insertAfter('.eaList>p.date');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

    <ul>
        <li class="eaList">
            <p class="title">
                Title
            </p>
            <p class="date">
                20/20/20
            </p>

        </li>
        <li class="eaList">
            <p class="title">
                Title
            </p>
            <p class="date">
                20/20/20
            </p>

        </li>
        <li class="eaList">
            <p class="title">
                Title
            </p>
            <p class="date">
                20/20/20
            </p>

        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```